# modeling unit donwn time in R

Tags: r

I am trying to model a power generation unit in R which looks at a column in data frame (available (1/0)) to start (1) and it stops (0) once the reference value becomes zero. But once it stops there is a minimum shut down interval, therefore it cant start right away even if the value of available is 1.

example:
available(reference column)[1100111]
unit (to be modelled)      [1100011]
unit cant start as early as 6th step as there is a minimum downtime of 3 hours

Help is highly appreciated.

here is an excel sample file showing what i want to achieve. 
http://www.filedropper.com/sample_5

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [How to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it is easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**1) regexpr** If the problem is to find the first 1 immediately following two consecutive 0s and return 0 if none then:

```
x <- c("1100011", "010101") # test data

r <- regexpr("001", x)
ifelse(r > 0, r + 2, 0)
## [1]  6 0
```

**2) rollapplyr** Another possibility is to split the string into one character strings and then use `rollappyr` to find the `c("0", "0", "1")` subsequences taking the first.

```
library(zoo)

spl <- strsplit(x, "")
roll <- function(x) which.max(rollapplyr(x, 3, identical, c("0", "0", "1"), fill = FALSE))
out <- sapply(spl, roll)
out <- ifelse(out == 1, 0, out)
out
## [1]  6 0
```

Comment: thanks for all the support but i think my description of problem was not so elaborative.

Comment: here is the link to a sample excel file which shows what i want to achieve in R. original data set is too big to be shared. http://www.filedropper.com/sample_5